# How to speed up a Windows batch file containing calls to a couple awk scripts?

Tags: performance, batch-file, awk, command-line

I wrote a batch file which calls a couple awk scripts that I created (append and footnote):

```
@ECHO off

type compiler-books.txt | awk -f append -v filename="economics-books.txt" | awk -f footnote
```

I added some commands to the batch file to determine how much time is being taken to run the awk scripts:

```
@ECHO off

set start_date=%date% %time%

type compiler-books.txt | awk -f append -v filename="economics-books.txt" | awk -f footnote

set end_date=%date% %time%
powershell -command "&{$start_date1 = [datetime]::parse('%start_date%'); $end_date1 = [datetime]::parse('%date% %time%'); echo (-join('Duration in seconds: ', ($end_date1 - $start_date1).TotalSeconds)); }"
```

The result is that it takes about half a second to run the awk scripts. Eek! Half a second to run two simple awk scripts on two tiny input files! That is terrible. Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

Below are my awk scripts and the tiny input files (compiler-books.txt and economics-books.txt)

Here is the "append" awk script:

```
BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}
      { print }
END   {
        while ((getline < filename) > 0)
           print
      }
```

Here is the "footnote" awk script:

```
BEGIN   {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}
NR==1   { print; author_list=$2 }
NR>1    { print; author_list=author_list ", " $2 }
END     { print author_list}
```

Here is the tab-delimited compiler-books.txt file:

```
Compilers Principles, Techniques, Tools Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman   Addison-Wesley  1986
Introduction to Compiling Techniques    J. P. Bennett   McGraw-Hill 1996
```

Here is tab-delimited economics-books.txt file:

```
Economic Facts and Fallacies    Thomas Sowell   Basic Books 2011
Economics in One Lesson Henry Hazlitt   Harper & Brothers   1946
```

Comment: Did you measure the timing for each awk file separately? Or do you try to combine the two scripts? Or check it without pipes, one by one

Comment: If you're using `PowerShell` anyhow, why not just perform the task in that? You should also understand that your command line is more technically, ```(type compiler-books.txt) | ((awk -f append -v filename="economics-books.txt") | (awk -f footnote))```

Comment: What version of awk are you using (what does `awk --version` output)?

Comment: Doesn't Windows have some equivalent of the Unix `cat` command that'd let you replace `type compiler-books.txt | awk -f append -v filename="economics-books.txt"` with just `cat compiler-books.txt economics-books.txt`? If not, `awk '1' compiler-books.txt economics-books.txt` would do that but it's not necessary to have multiple commands and a pipeline at all best I can tell, just run `footnote` on both input files.

Comment: Hello @Daweo I am using this version of awk: GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: Hello @Compo Would things run faster in PowerShell?

Comment: Hello @Ed Morton I like how you've grouped things using parentheses. That makes it much clearer. Thank you!

Comment: Twas I, not Ed Morton, @RogerCostello.

Answer (score 3):

Those awk scripts will run in the blink of an eye, more time will be spent by the OS starting the processes, opening files, managing pipelines, etc. than in the actual scripts. Can't you just run this 1 command instead of calling 3 separate commands in a pipeline:

```
awk -f footnote compiler-books.txt economics-books.txt
```

FWIW on my old laptop running cygwin the equivalent Unix operation takes 0.13 secs:

```
$ time { cat compiler-books.txt | awk -f append -v filename="economics-books.txt" | awk -f footnote; }
Compilers Principles, Techniques, Tools Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman       Addison-Wesley  1986
Introduction to Compiling Techniques    J. P. Bennett   McGraw-Hill     1996
Economic Facts and Fallacies    Thomas Sowell   Basic Books     2011
Economics in One Lesson Henry Hazlitt   Harper & Brothers       1946
Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman, J. P. Bennett, Thomas Sowell, Henry Hazlitt

real    0m0.134s
user    0m0.045s
sys     0m0.015s
```

while using the single script I suggested takes less than 0.09s:

```
$ time awk -f footnote compiler-books.txt economics-books.txt
Compilers Principles, Techniques, Tools Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman       Addison-Wesley  1986
Introduction to Compiling Techniques    J. P. Bennett   McGraw-Hill     1996
Economic Facts and Fallacies    Thomas Sowell   Basic Books     2011
Economics in One Lesson Henry Hazlitt   Harper & Brothers       1946
Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman, J. P. Bennett, Thomas Sowell, Henry Hazlitt

real    0m0.087s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.030s
```

You are using `getline` unnecessarily (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) in the first script and in the second you're constantly appending to a variable which is a very slow operation as it requires awk to constantly have to find new memory to move it to every time it grows but again, that's not going to cause your scripts to run too slow for your needs.

In fact here's a single awk script that combines everything you're doing in your pipeline so you can see how fast the awk operations are compared to how fast your 3-command pipeline executed above, the difference there being the OS overhead, and how fast it is compared to the single call to "footnote" above, the difference there being improved awk code:

```
$ cat doitall
BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS="\t" }
NR==1 { print; author_list=$2 }
NR>1  { print; author_list=author_list ", " $2 }
END   {
          while ((getline < filename) > 0) {
              print; author_list=author_list ", " $2
          }
          print author_list
      }
```

```
$ time awk -f doitall -v filename="economics-books.txt" compiler-books.txt
Compilers Principles, Techniques, Tools Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman       Addison-Wesley  1986
Introduction to Compiling Techniques    J. P. Bennett   McGraw-Hill     1996
Economic Facts and Fallacies    Thomas Sowell   Basic Books     2011
Economics in One Lesson Henry Hazlitt   Harper & Brothers       1946
Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman, J. P. Bennett, Thomas Sowell, Henry Hazlitt

real    0m0.102s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Comment: Hello @Ed Morton Thank you for your detailed and excellent response! The reason for calling three separate commands in a pipeline is to illustrate a way of doing software development (create independent, general tools that are connected via command line operators such as "pipe" and "type"). So I do not want to do it all in one command. It sounds like what you are saying is that this approach to software development suffers from the large overhead of "the OS starting the processes, opening files, managing pipelines, etc." and that overhead is inescapable. Is that true?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that is true. I wouldn't say it's a large overhead, though, it's just that it is large in comparison to what your scripts are doing. If you had complex scripts and/or large files then you wouldn't notice the OS overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` approach that eliminates a) the `filename` variable, b) the use of `getline` and c) the conditionals:

```
time awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="\t" }
        { print
          author_list=author_list sep $2
          sep=", "
        }
END     { print author_list }
' compiler-books.txt economics-books.txt
```

This generates:

```
Compilers Principles, Techniques, Tools Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman       Addison-Wesley  1986
Introduction to Compiling Techniques    J. P. Bennett   McGraw-Hill     1996
Economic Facts and Fallacies    Thomas Sowell   Basic Books     2011
Economics in One Lesson Henry Hazlitt   Harper & Brothers       1946
Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman, J. P. Bennett, Thomas Sowell, Henry Hazlitt

real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness you could compare with other utilities, e.g., GNU `sed`:

```bash
$ time sed -En 'p;s/[^\t]*\t([^\t]*).*/\1/;H;${x;s/\n/, /g;s/^, //;p}' compiler-books.txt economics-books.txt
Compilers Principles, Techniques, Tools Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman   Addison-Wesley  1986
Introduction to Compiling Techniques    J. P. Bennett   McGraw-Hill 1996
Economic Facts and Fallacies    Thomas Sowell   Basic Books 2011
Economics in One Lesson Henry Hazlitt   Harper & Brothers   1946
Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey Ullman, J. P. Bennett, Thomas Sowell, Henry Hazlitt

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.003s
```